# Javascript while loop not looping

Tags: javascript

It mostly works, but when it hits, it does not loop.  What have I done wrong with the while loop?

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
var totalDamage = 0;

while(slaying){
    if(youHit){
        console.log("You hit the dragon.");
        totalDamage += damageThisRound;
        if(totalDamage>=4){
            console.log("You slew the dragon.");
            slaying=false;
        }else{
            youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
        }
    }else{
        console.log("The dragon defeated you.");
    }
    slaying = false;
}
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript, also paste your code here.

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems like the variable `slaying` becomes false during the first iteration. That's why it doesn't loop.

Comment: Seems like you've picked the wrong book from the shelf last night

Comment: Aw man I just finished rewriting your code moments before you added it..

Answer (score 2):

The variable `slaying` is always set to `false` at the end of the loop, so it never iterates more than once.